# Simulating key press events in Mac OS X

Tags: c++, cocoa, macos, keyboard, macos-carbon

I'm writing an app where I need to simulate key press events on a Mac, given a code that represents each key. It seems I need to use the `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` function to create the event. The problem is that this function needs a Mac keycode, and what I have is a code that represents the specific key. So, for example, I receive:

`KEY_CODE_SHIFT` or `KEY_CODE_A` - these are both numeric constants defined somewhere.

I need to take these constants and turn them into `CGKeyCode` values.

My current attempt uses code similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918841/how-to-convert-ascii-character-to-cgkeycode). The problem is that it only works for printable characters. If all else fails, I'm not above hard coding the conversion, but that would mean that I'd need a table of possible CGKeyCode values, which I have not yet been able to find.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's code to simulate a <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> action:

```
CGKeyCode inputKeyCode = kVK_ANSI_S;
CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
CGEventRef saveCommandDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, inputKeyCode, YES);
CGEventSetFlags(saveCommandDown, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
CGEventRef saveCommandUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, inputKeyCode, NO);

CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, saveCommandDown);
CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, saveCommandUp);

CFRelease(saveCommandUp);
CFRelease(saveCommandDown);
CFRelease(source);
```

A `CGKeyCode` is nothing more than an unsigned integer:

```
typedef uint16_t CGKeyCode;  //From CGRemoteOperation.h
```

Your real issue will be turning a character (probably an `NSString`) into a keycode.  Fortunately, the [Shortcut Recorder](https://github.com/shortcutrecorder/shortcutrecorder) project has code that will do just that in the [`SRKeyCodeTransformer.m`](https://github.com/shortcutrecorder/shortcutrecorder/tree/master/Framework/Source/SRKeyCodeTransformer.m) file.  It's great for transforming a string to a keycode and back again.

Comment: So in this example then, the `CGKeyCode` of `1` is the code for S? Also, would this work for just a foreground app, or if it was running in the background, would it work across the entire session? Thanks

Comment: So, say my app was running in the background (just as a service) and i had Photoshop in front, i could simulate a key press, and it would be seen in Photoshop? Thanks

Comment: @joec yes, that's what would happen

Comment: @Dave, do you have code that utilises SRKeyCodeTransformer? I have added the ShortcutRecorder framework to my project, but unsure really where to go from here. Thanks.

Comment: @Dave. Thx for your code. I use your code and it seems to work perfect on most of apps except finder. 

From this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186317/why-copy-and-paste-in-finder-doesnt-work-when-i-use-registereventhotkey-cocoa), I try your code and it doesn't work on finder. Let's say I press cmd+C and finder does not copy selected files.

Comment: You can use the kVK_??? constants instead of plain numbers. Thanks for the snippet. It really helped.

Comment: Anyone have any examples which use ARC? I can't get the shortcut recorder code to compile in a ARC project.

Comment: Instead of using 1 use **kVK_ANSI_S** and replace S with any key you want

Answer (score 7):

Just in case some one needs a Swift version:

XCode 7.3 and Swift 2.2:

```
let event1 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(nil, 0x09, true); // cmd-v down
CGEventSetFlags(event1, CGEventFlags.MaskCommand);
CGEventPost(CGEventTapLocation.CGHIDEventTap, event1);

let event2 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(nil, 0x09, false); // cmd-v up
CGEventSetFlags(event2, CGEventFlags.MaskCommand);
CGEventPost(CGEventTapLocation.CGHIDEventTap, event2);
```

Code above simulates CMD-V pressed then released(AKA: paste).