# Why copy and paste in finder doesn't work when I use RegisterEventHotKey (Cocoa)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon, hotkeys, finder

I use function RegisterEventHotKey() and when I try registering Cmd + C or Cmd + V, I notice that copy and paste in finder doesn't work.

I insert parameter inOptions = 0 to function RegisterEventHotKey() so it should non-exclusiv but why finder seem not to receive this hot key?

```
EventTypeSpec eventType;
eventType.eventClass=kEventClassKeyboard;
eventType.eventKind=kEventHotKeyPressed;
InstallApplicationEventHandler(&MyHotKeyHandler,1,&eventType,(void *)self,NULL);

EventHotKeyID gMyHotKeyID;
NSInteger keycode = 8; // 'C'

UInt32 modkey=0;
modkey+=cmdKey;
RegisterEventHotKey((int)keycode, modkey, gMyHotKeyID,
                        GetApplicationEventTarget(), 0, &hotkeyRef);


//
OSStatus MyHotKeyHandler(EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler,EventRef theEvent,
                         void *userData)
{
    NSLog(@"test hot key");
    return eventNotHandledErr;
}
```

Here is the code. When I click cmd+C, it show log "test hot key" but finder did not copy selected files.

*My application is agent. has menu bar and always run in the background.

Comment: Please post the exact code that you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because when you install a hot key handler, *you replace the default functionality of that key combination in every app*.

Comment: Thx. So is there a way to receive cmd+C hotkey while finder still can use this combination?

Comment: You would have to pass the key combination along to the Finder. Take a look at `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent()` and `CGEventPostToPSN()`.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I did as you suggest and found that it works on other applications except finder... How come?