# Adobe Air Keyboard Native Extension (OSX)

Tags: macos, air, air-native-extension

I would like to make an adobe air desktop (OSX) application what can control the Keynote (slide right, and left). I find the easiest way to make a Native Extension, what is 'pressing' the left and right arrow keys. I find this: [Simulating key press events in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379867/simulating-key-press-events-in-mac-os-x)

Ok its work in a CocoaApplication, but I need to make a Static Library (.a) for NA. But here is the problem:

I can't add the Cocoa.framework library into my project. Any Idea, how could I use this? Or any other tips? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My Fail! I made Cocoa Touch static library not, Cocoa Static Library