# Keyboard emulation in python, cross platform

Tags: python, scripting, hotkeys, hid

I couldn't find a way to do this on Mac and Linux.  With Windows one could use `ctypes` and then use `console.SendKeys`.  So far as I can tell there is certainly no way that Apple would let a humble user take over the mouse and keyboard, but how might an average Joe do this on Linux?  Despite no findings, I would assume there is some way to do this through an X-server?

Any input, in any programming language, is very welcome

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87839/14502

Comment: @JohnZwinck, I've heard of xdotool, I recall having tried this in the past. I did notice it has a C library, but it hasn't been updated recently. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: On Linux you can also use uinput to inject the input events at the kernel level if you need to, but the X11 approach seems simpler. For OS X a quick search found this, which should work through ctypes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379867/simulating-key-press-events-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uinput is the definitive, Kernel-guru sanctioned way to do this on Linux.
Thanks to @Reily Grant for the Mac info!