# Where can I find a list of Mac virtual key codes?

Tags: macos, keyboard, quartz-graphics, keycode, cgkeycode

I'm using `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` and need to know what `CGKeyCode` values to use.

Specifically, I am after the key code for the <kbd>Command</kbd> key. The docs give examples for other keys: <kbd>z</kbd> is `6`, <kbd>shift</kbd> is `56`.

There must be a list of Mac virtual keycodes somewhere?

Comment: Get my code here: 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918841/how-to-convert-ascii-character-to-cgkeycode/14529841#14529841][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918841/how-to-convert-ascii-character-to-cgkeycode/14529841#14529841

Comment: [W3C DOM Level 3 KeyboardEvent code Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-code-20150428/)

Comment: @davidcondrey The key codes used by Javascript are unrelated. They're entirely different from the virtual key codes used by macOS.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Below is a list of the common key codes for quick reference, taken from `Events.h`.

If you need to use these keycodes in an application, you should include the Carbon framework:

Objective-C:
`#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>`

Swift:
`import Carbon.HIToolbox`

You can then use the `kVK_ANSI_A` constants directly.

---

#### WARNING

The key constants reference **physical keys** on the keyboard. Their output changes if the typist is using a different keyboard layout. The letters in the constants correspond only to the U.S. QWERTY keyboard layout.

For example, the left ring-finger key on the homerow:

`QWERTY keyboard layout` > <kbd>s</kbd> > `kVK_ANSI_S` > `"s"`
`Dvorak keyboard layout` > <kbd>o</kbd> > `kVK_ANSI_S` > `"o"`

Strategies for layout-agnostic conversion of keycode to string, and vice versa, are discussed here:

[How to convert ASCII character to CGKeyCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918841/how-to-convert-ascii-character-to-cgkeycode)

---

From `Events.h`:

```
/*
 *  Summary:
 *    Virtual keycodes
 *  
 *  Discussion:
 *    These constants are the virtual keycodes defined originally in
 *    Inside Mac Volume V, pg. V-191. They identify physical keys on a
 *    keyboard. Those constants with "ANSI" in the name are labeled
 *    according to the key position on an ANSI-standard US keyboard.
 *    For example, kVK_ANSI_A indicates the virtual keycode for the key
 *    with the letter 'A' in the US keyboard layout. Other keyboard
 *    layouts may have the 'A' key label on a different physical key;
 *    in this case, pressing 'A' will generate a different virtual
 *    keycode.
 */
enum {
  kVK_ANSI_A                    = 0x00,
  kVK_ANSI_S                    = 0x01,
  kVK_ANSI_D                    = 0x02,
  kVK_ANSI_F                    = 0x03,
  kVK_ANSI_H                    = 0x04,
  kVK_ANSI_G                    = 0x05,
  kVK_ANSI_Z                    = 0x06,
  kVK_ANSI_X                    = 0x07,
  kVK_ANSI_C                    = 0x08,
  kVK_ANSI_V                    = 0x09,
  kVK_ANSI_B                    = 0x0B,
  kVK_ANSI_Q                    = 0x0C,
  kVK_ANSI_W                    = 0x0D,
  kVK_ANSI_E                    = 0x0E,
  kVK_ANSI_R                    = 0x0F,
  kVK_ANSI_Y                    = 0x10,
  kVK_ANSI_T                    = 0x11,
  kVK_ANSI_1                    = 0x12,
  kVK_ANSI_2                    = 0x13,
  kVK_ANSI_3                    = 0x14,
  kVK_ANSI_4                    = 0x15,
  kVK_ANSI_6                    = 0x16,
  kVK_ANSI_5                    = 0x17,
  kVK_ANSI_Equal                = 0x18,
  kVK_ANSI_9                    = 0x19,
  kVK_ANSI_7                    = 0x1A,
  kVK_ANSI_Minus                = 0x1B,
  kVK_ANSI_8                    = 0x1C,
  kVK_ANSI_0                    = 0x1D,
  kVK_ANSI_RightBracket         = 0x1E,
  kVK_ANSI_O                    = 0x1F,
  kVK_ANSI_U                    = 0x20,
  kVK_ANSI_LeftBracket          = 0x21,
  kVK_ANSI_I                    = 0x22,
  kVK_ANSI_P                    = 0x23,
  kVK_ANSI_L                    = 0x25,
  kVK_ANSI_J                    = 0x26,
  kVK_ANSI_Quote                = 0x27,
  kVK_ANSI_K                    = 0x28,
  kVK_ANSI_Semicolon            = 0x29,
  kVK_ANSI_Backslash            = 0x2A,
  kVK_ANSI_Comma                = 0x2B,
  kVK_ANSI_Slash                = 0x2C,
  kVK_ANSI_N                    = 0x2D,
  kVK_ANSI_M                    = 0x2E,
  kVK_ANSI_Period               = 0x2F,
  kVK_ANSI_Grave                = 0x32,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadDecimal        = 0x41,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadMultiply       = 0x43,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadPlus           = 0x45,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadClear          = 0x47,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadDivide         = 0x4B,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadEnter          = 0x4C,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadMinus          = 0x4E,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadEquals         = 0x51,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad0              = 0x52,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad1              = 0x53,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad2              = 0x54,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad3              = 0x55,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad4              = 0x56,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad5              = 0x57,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad6              = 0x58,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad7              = 0x59,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad8              = 0x5B,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad9              = 0x5C
};

/* keycodes for keys that are independent of keyboard layout*/
enum {
  kVK_Return                    = 0x24,
  kVK_Tab                       = 0x30,
  kVK_Space                     = 0x31,
  kVK_Delete                    = 0x33,
  kVK_Escape                    = 0x35,
  kVK_Command                   = 0x37,
  kVK_Shift                     = 0x38,
  kVK_CapsLock                  = 0x39,
  kVK_Option                    = 0x3A,
  kVK_Control                   = 0x3B,
  kVK_RightShift                = 0x3C,
  kVK_RightOption               = 0x3D,
  kVK_RightControl              = 0x3E,
  kVK_Function                  = 0x3F,
  kVK_F17                       = 0x40,
  kVK_VolumeUp                  = 0x48,
  kVK_VolumeDown                = 0x49,
  kVK_Mute                      = 0x4A,
  kVK_F18                       = 0x4F,
  kVK_F19                       = 0x50,
  kVK_F20                       = 0x5A,
  kVK_F5                        = 0x60,
  kVK_F6                        = 0x61,
  kVK_F7                        = 0x62,
  kVK_F3                        = 0x63,
  kVK_F8                        = 0x64,
  kVK_F9                        = 0x65,
  kVK_F11                       = 0x67,
  kVK_F13                       = 0x69,
  kVK_F16                       = 0x6A,
  kVK_F14                       = 0x6B,
  kVK_F10                       = 0x6D,
  kVK_F12                       = 0x6F,
  kVK_F15                       = 0x71,
  kVK_Help                      = 0x72,
  kVK_Home                      = 0x73,
  kVK_PageUp                    = 0x74,
  kVK_ForwardDelete             = 0x75,
  kVK_F4                        = 0x76,
  kVK_End                       = 0x77,
  kVK_F2                        = 0x78,
  kVK_PageDown                  = 0x79,
  kVK_F1                        = 0x7A,
  kVK_LeftArrow                 = 0x7B,
  kVK_RightArrow                = 0x7C,
  kVK_DownArrow                 = 0x7D,
  kVK_UpArrow                   = 0x7E
};
```

[Macintosh Toolbox Essentials](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/mac/pdf/MacintoshToolboxEssentials.pdf) illustrates the physical locations of these virtual key codes for the Apple Extended Keyboard II in `Figure 2-10`:

[image: Virtual key codes for the Apple Extended Keyboard II]

Comment: For visualization, check out the Virtual key codes for the Apple Extended Keyboard II from the Macintosh Toolbox Essentials available **[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160509091827/http://x86osx.com/bbs/c_data/pds_comment/MacintoshToolboxEssentials.pdf)**.

Comment: worth mentioning events.h can be found at /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers

Comment: Which key code is Power Button?

Comment: @MichałZiobro The Power Key/Button is a bit tricky, generating several `NSSystemDefined`-type keyboard events with various keycodes and subtypes such as `NX_POWER_KEY` and `NX_SUBTYPE_POWER_KEY`. Please see source of my `PowerKey` app on github for more information: https://github.com/pkamb/PowerKey/blob/master/PowerKey/PKPowerKeyEventListener.m

Comment: Why are some keys missing, such as 0x66 or 0x68 (but 0x67 exists)...?

Comment: Why aren't these static constants on the Event class?

Comment: What about the microphone key on newer MacBooks? I couldn't find any resource stating the virtual key code for this key, but I need it for my application as this key is the default for the dictation feature from MacOS on newer MacBook devices :( It seems like this key does not have any key code at all. My code reads the current configuration to extract the current shortcut for the dictation feature and then triggers a virtual keypress event, so that the dictation feature can be used programmatically, but it fails for MacBook devices which have the microphone key assigned by default.

Answer (score 81):

The more canonical reference is in `<HIToolbox/Events.h>`:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h
```

In newer Versions of MacOS the "Events.h" moved to here:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h
```

Comment: Note, too, that if you include `<Carbon/Carbon.h>` (or this header directly), the `kVK_*` symbols are exposed. So in your example, you can use `kVK_Command` directly.

Comment: @MattB. +1 for `#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>`. You can then just type `kVK_ANSI_A`.

Comment: Using character codes from Events.h works great for the new iOS7 UIKeyCommand api as well

Comment: In Swift, `import Carbon.HIToolbox` to access these constants.

Comment: I read on [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SystemFrameworks/SystemFrameworks.html) that Carbon's HIToolbox.framework is deprecated. But I can't find a replacement in Cocoa.framework. Did they deprecate this without providing a replacement? Is it safe to use this Carbon framework in modern apps?

Answer (score 19):

Found an answer [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100501161453/http://www.classicteck.com/rbarticles/mackeyboard.php).

So:

- Command key is 55
- Shift is 56
- Caps Lock 57
- Option is 58
- Control is 59.

Comment: ...and image is broken on archive.org version.

Comment: It's ok on older snapshot (e.g https://web.archive.org/web/20080227222056/http://classicteck.com/rbarticles/mackeyboard.php)

Answer (score 7):

Here are the all keycodes.

> Here is a table with some keycodes for the three platforms. It is based on a US Extended keyboard layout.

http://web.archive.org/web/20100501161453/http://www.classicteck.com/rbarticles/mackeyboard.php

Or, there is an app in the Mac App Store named "Key Codes". Download it to see the keycodes of the keys you press.

Key Codes:
https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/key-codes/id414568915?l=tr&mt=12

Answer (score 7):

I found this wonderful [article](https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes) while doing the research for [LibOS](https://github.com/gavrilikhin-d/libos).

[image]

P.S: Mac's virtual key codes are the worst

Comment: I'm trying to engage F8 to play pause whatever the system is doing with that button. Anybody has some way of doing that?

Comment: difference of "shortcut" and "keycode". A shortcut is meant to be remembered by user versus a keycode is meant to not change at all. That way a key can output different letters in different layouts. Thats not 'worst', it is the purpose. example: key on the right side of the left most shift-key can be "W","Z",">" ... but has always the same keycode, therefore the letter is requested with the keycode and results in according letter chosen by the users layout.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the keycodes supplied in other answers, there are also "usage IDs" used for key remapping in the newer APIs introduced in macOS Sierra:

> Technical Note TN2450
>
> Remapping Keys in macOS 10.12 Sierra
>
> Under macOS Sierra 10.12, the mechanism for key remapping was changed. This Technical Note is for developers of key remapping software so that they can update their software to support macOS Sierra 10.12. We present 2 solutions for implementing key remapping functionality for macOS 10.12 in this Technical Note.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html

```
Keyboard a and A - 0x04
Keyboard b and B - 0x05
Keyboard c and C - 0x06
Keyboard d and D - 0x07
Keyboard e and E - 0x08
...
```

Comment: Note that the values from this table differ from what you get out of `NSEvent.keyCode`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some prebuilt Objective-C dictionaries if anyone wants to type ansi characters:

```
NSDictionary *lowerCaseCodes = @{
                                @"Q" : @(12),
                                @"W" : @(13),
                                @"E" : @(14),
                                @"R" : @(15),
                                @"T" : @(17),
                                @"Y" : @(16),
                                @"U" : @(32),
                                @"I" : @(34),
                                @"O" : @(31),
                                @"P" : @(35),
                                @"A" : @(0),
                                @"S" : @(1),
                                @"D" : @(2),
                                @"F" : @(3),
                                @"G" : @(5),
                                @"H" : @(4),
                                @"J" : @(38),
                                @"K" : @(40),
                                @"L" : @(37),
                                @"Z" : @(6),
                                @"X" : @(7),
                                @"C" : @(8),
                                @"V" : @(9),
                                @"B" : @(11),
                                @"N" : @(45),
                                @"M" : @(46),
                                @"0" : @(29),
                                @"1" : @(18),
                                @"2" : @(19),
                                @"3" : @(20),
                                @"4" : @(21),
                                @"5" : @(23),
                                @"6" : @(22),
                                @"7" : @(26),
                                @"8" : @(28),
                                @"9" : @(25),
                                @" " : @(49),
                                @"." : @(47),
                                @"," : @(43),
                                @"/" : @(44),
                                @";" : @(41),
                                @"'" : @(39),
                                @"[" : @(33),
                                @"]" : @(30),
                                @"\\" : @(42),
                                @"-" : @(27),
                                @"=" : @(24)
                                };

NSDictionary *shiftCodes = @{ // used in conjunction with the shift key
                                @"<" : @(43),
                                @">" : @(47),
                                @"?" : @(44),
                                @":" : @(41),
                                @"\"" : @(39),
                                @"{" : @(33),
                                @"}" : @(30),
                                @"|" : @(42),
                                @")" : @(29),
                                @"!" : @(18),
                                @"@" : @(19),
                                @"#" : @(20),
                                @"$" : @(21),
                                @"%" : @(23),
                                @"^" : @(22),
                                @"&" : @(26),
                                @"*" : @(28),
                                @"(" : @(25),
                                @"_" : @(27),
                                @"+" : @(24)
                                };
```

Comment: using `@(42)` cuts down on the noise of `numberWithInteger: 42`. But a lookup table like this is not a good idea due to the mismatch on other keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 0):

### macOS 10.12+

Since macOS Sierra 10.12, `keyCode` has been according to the [Universal Serial Bus HID Usage Tables](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf) (go to section: 10 Keyboard/Keypad Page, page 51).

```
Usage           Usage ID (hex)
Keyboard a and A        0x04
Keyboard b and B        0x05
Keyboard c and C        0x06
Keyboard d and D        0x07
Keyboard e and E        0x08
Keyboard f and F        0x09
Keyboard g and G        0x0A
Keyboard h and H        0x0B
Keyboard i and I        0x0C
Keyboard j and J        0x0D
Keyboard k and K        0x0E
Keyboard l and L        0x0F
Keyboard m and M        0x10
Keyboard n and N        0x11
Keyboard o and O        0x12
Keyboard p and P        0x13
Keyboard q and Q        0x14
Keyboard r and R        0x15
Keyboard s and S        0x16
Keyboard t and T        0x17
Keyboard u and U        0x18
Keyboard v and V        0x19
Keyboard w and W        0x1A
Keyboard x and X        0x1B
Keyboard y and Y        0x1C
Keyboard z and Z        0x1D
Keyboard 1 and !        0x1E
Keyboard 2 and @        0x1F
Keyboard 3 and #        0x20
Keyboard 4 and $        0x21
Keyboard 5 and %        0x22
Keyboard 6 and ^        0x23
Keyboard 7 and &        0x24
Keyboard 8 and *        0x25
Keyboard 9 and (        0x26
Keyboard 0 and )        0x27
Keyboard Return (Enter) 0x28
Keyboard Escape         0x29
Keyboard Delete (Backspace)0x2A
Keyboard Tab            0x2B
Keyboard Spacebar       0x2C
Keyboard - and _        0x2D
Keyboard = and +        0x2E
Keyboard [ and {        0x2F
Keyboard ] and }        0x30
Keyboard \ and |        0x31
Keyboard Non-US # and ~ 0x32
Keyboard ; and :        0x33
Keyboard ' and "        0x34
Keyboard Grave Accent and Tilde 0x35
Keyboard , and "<"      0x36
Keyboard . and ">"      0x37
Keyboard / and ?        0x38
Keyboard Caps Lock      0x39
Keyboard F1             0x3A
Keyboard F2             0x3B
Keyboard F3             0x3C
Keyboard F4             0x3D
Keyboard F5             0x3E
Keyboard F6             0x3F
Keyboard F7             0x40
Keyboard F8             0x41
Keyboard F9             0x42
Keyboard F10            0x43
Keyboard F11            0x44
Keyboard F12            0x45
Keyboard Print Screen   0x46
Keyboard Scroll Lock    0x47
Keyboard Pause          0x48
Keyboard Insert         0x49
Keyboard Home           0x4A
Keyboard Page Up        0x4B
Keyboard Delete Forward 0x4C
Keyboard End            0x4D
Keyboard Page Down      0x4E
Keyboard Right Arrow    0x4F
Keyboard Left Arrow     0x50
Keyboard Down Arrow     0x51
Keyboard Up Arrow       0x52
Keypad Num Lock and Clear   0x53
Keypad /                0x54
Keypad *                0x55
Keypad -                0x56
Keypad +                0x57
Keypad Enter            0x58
Keypad 1 and End        0x59
Keypad 2 and Down Arrow 0x5A
Keypad 3 and Page Down  0x5B
Keypad 4 and Left Arrow 0x5C
Keypad 5                0x5D
Keypad 6 and Right Arrow    0x5E
Keypad 7 and Home       0x5F
Keypad 8 and Up Arrow   0x60
Keypad 9 and Page Up    0x61
Keypad 0 and Insert     0x62
Keypad . and Delete     0x63
Keyboard Non-US \ and | 0x64
Keyboard Application    0x65
Keyboard Power          0x66
Keypad =                0x67
Keyboard F13            0x68
Keyboard F14            0x69
Keyboard F15            0x6A
Keyboard F16            0x6B
Keyboard F17            0x6C
Keyboard F18            0x6D
Keyboard F19            0x6E
Keyboard F20            0x6F
Keyboard F21            0x70
Keyboard F22            0x71
Keyboard F23            0x72
Keyboard F24            0x73
Keyboard Left Control   0xE0
Keyboard Left Shift     0xE1
Keyboard Left Alt       0xE2
Keyboard Left GUI       0xE3
Keyboard Right Control  0xE4
Keyboard Right Shift    0xE5
Keyboard Right Alt      0xE6
Keyboard Right GUI      0xE7
```

Comment: Apparently those codes don't apply to macOS Ventura (13)