# How to generate keyboard keypress events through Python to control PP presentation?

Tags: python, macos, keypress

I need to programmatically control powerpoint/pdf presentations (the 4 direction keystrokes need to work at the minimum to go to the previous and next slides).

What library/module/framework can I use with Python to do this on OS X?

I've seen a lot of discussion on doing this in Windows and C# (or OS X and Quartz), but nothing particularly with Python. A cross-platform library / framework would be even better.

Overall, I would like to programmatically control my presentation with Python on OS X (as part of a hobby project, and probably also useful in my own short presentations).

Comment: Sorry deleted my answer, somehow I managed to miss the [tag:osx], sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [PyQt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) or [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/)

Here is a link for how to handle key press with PyQt - http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-capture-tab-key-press-event-with/

and for wxPython - http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.KeyEvent-class.html
and http://zetcode.com/wxpython/events/

Comment: Thanks, but aren't these modules for **collecting** keypress events? Please let me know if I am wrong. I want to generate events, so as to move the presentation to the next slide, through code.

Comment: Just to clarify, e.g., I want to move to the next slide after a timer of 1 minute runs down. So I want to write a command that generates the 'forward key' event on the presentation window after 1 minute.

Comment: Sorry I assumed you were creating the presentation program in Python. One suggestion and I know this is not in Python, but have you looked at AppleScript ? As for a cross platform Python library to send keyboard events to the operating system , the only thing I came across is this using wxPython - http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Create-a-mouse-keyboard-event-and-send-to-the-underlying-OS-td4400077.html

Comment: Thanks! Applescript looks promising. Seems like there isn't a good way to achieve this with Python itself.

Comment: I doubt if there is a cross platform library for doing things like this. wxPython, Qt and similar GUI libraries probably have features like this but aren't built really for this purpose. You could use OS dependent libraries such as http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/ for OS X and http://python.net/crew/skippy/win32/ for Win32, but this would fall under slightly advanced programming.

Comment: `py-appscript` lets you do Applescripting in Python: http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/index.html

Comment: Thanks, that bridge should be very useful!

Comment: Would this be able to work with an inactive/minimized window?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Quartz` library for Python, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Script simulating keyboard events in macOS.
# See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13564851/55075

import sys
import time
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventPost
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGHIDEventTap
#from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CFRelease # Python releases things automatically.

class Keyboard():
    shiftChars = {
        '~': '`',
        '!': '1',
        '@': '2',
        '#': '3',
        '$': '4',
        '%': '5',
        '^': '6',
        '&': '7',
        '*': '8',
        '(': '9',
        ')': '0',
        '_': '-',
        '+': '=',
        '{': '[',
        '}': ']',
        '|': '\\',
        ':': ';',
        '"': '\'',
        '<': ',',
        '>': '.',
        '?': '/'
    }


    keyCodeMap = {
        'a'              : 0x00,
        's'              : 0x01,
        'd'              : 0x02,
        'f'              : 0x03,
        'h'              : 0x04,
        'g'              : 0x05,
        'z'              : 0x06,
        'x'              : 0x07,
        'c'              : 0x08,
        'v'              : 0x09,
        'b'              : 0x0B,
        'q'              : 0x0C,
        'w'              : 0x0D,
        'e'              : 0x0E,
        'r'              : 0x0F,
        'y'              : 0x10,
        't'              : 0x11,
        '1'              : 0x12,
        '2'              : 0x13,
        '3'              : 0x14,
        '4'              : 0x15,
        '6'              : 0x16,
        '5'              : 0x17,
        '='              : 0x18,
        '9'              : 0x19,
        '7'              : 0x1A,
        '-'              : 0x1B,
        '8'              : 0x1C,
        '0'              : 0x1D,
        ']'              : 0x1E,
        'o'              : 0x1F,
        'u'              : 0x20,
        '['              : 0x21,
        'i'              : 0x22,
        'p'              : 0x23,
        'l'              : 0x25,
        'j'              : 0x26,
        '\''             : 0x27,
        'k'              : 0x28,
        ';'              : 0x29,
        '\\'             : 0x2A,
        ','              : 0x2B,
        '/'              : 0x2C,
        'n'              : 0x2D,
        'm'              : 0x2E,
        '.'              : 0x2F,
        '`'              : 0x32,
        'k.'             : 0x41,
        'k*'             : 0x43,
        'k+'             : 0x45,
        'kclear'         : 0x47,
        'k/'             : 0x4B,
        'k\n'            : 0x4C,
        'k-'             : 0x4E,
        'k='             : 0x51,
        'k0'             : 0x52,
        'k1'             : 0x53,
        'k2'             : 0x54,
        'k3'             : 0x55,
        'k4'             : 0x56,
        'k5'             : 0x57,
        'k6'             : 0x58,
        'k7'             : 0x59,
        'k8'             : 0x5B,
        'k9'             : 0x5C,

        # keycodes for keys that are independent of keyboard layout
        '\n'             : 0x24,
        '\t'             : 0x30,
        ' '              : 0x31,
        'del'            : 0x33,
        'delete'         : 0x33,
        'esc'            : 0x35,
        'escape'         : 0x35,
        'cmd'            : 0x37,
        'command'        : 0x37,
        'shift'          : 0x38,
        'caps lock'      : 0x39,
        'option'         : 0x3A,
        'ctrl'           : 0x3B,
        'control'        : 0x3B,
        'right shift'    : 0x3C,
        'rshift'         : 0x3C,
        'right option'   : 0x3D,
        'roption'        : 0x3D,
        'right control'  : 0x3E,
        'rcontrol'       : 0x3E,
        'fun'            : 0x3F,
        'function'       : 0x3F,
        'f17'            : 0x40,
        'volume up'      : 0x48,
        'volume down'    : 0x49,
        'mute'           : 0x4A,
        'f18'            : 0x4F,
        'f19'            : 0x50,
        'f20'            : 0x5A,
        'f5'             : 0x60,
        'f6'             : 0x61,
        'f7'             : 0x62,
        'f3'             : 0x63,
        'f8'             : 0x64,
        'f9'             : 0x65,
        'f11'            : 0x67,
        'f13'            : 0x69,
        'f16'            : 0x6A,
        'f14'            : 0x6B,
        'f10'            : 0x6D,
        'f12'            : 0x6F,
        'f15'            : 0x71,
        'help'           : 0x72,
        'home'           : 0x73,
        'pgup'           : 0x74,
        'page up'        : 0x74,
        'forward delete' : 0x75,
        'f4'             : 0x76,
        'end'            : 0x77,
        'f2'             : 0x78,
        'page down'      : 0x79,
        'pgdn'           : 0x79,
        'f1'             : 0x7A,
        'left'           : 0x7B,
        'right'          : 0x7C,
        'down'           : 0x7D,
        'up'             : 0x7E
    }

    # See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3202629/55075
    def toKeyCode(self, c):
        shiftKey = False
        # Letter
        if c.isalpha():
            if not c.islower():
                shiftKey = True
                c = c.lower()
        if c in Keyboard.shiftChars:
            shiftKey = True
            c = Keyboard.shiftChars[c]
        if c in Keyboard.keyCodeMap:
            keyCode = Keyboard.keyCodeMap[c]
        else:
            keyCode = ord(c)
        return keyCode, shiftKey

    def KeyDown(self, k):
        keyCode, shiftKey = self.toKeyCode(k)

        time.sleep(0.0001)

        if shiftKey:
            CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x38, True))
            time.sleep(0.0001)

        CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, keyCode, True))
        time.sleep(0.0001)

        if shiftKey:
            CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x38, False))
            time.sleep(0.0001)

    def KeyUp(self, k):
        keyCode, shiftKey = self.toKeyCode(k)

        time.sleep(0.0001)

        CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, keyCode, False))
        time.sleep(0.0001)

    def KeyPress(self, k):
        keyCode, shiftKey = self.toKeyCode(k)

        time.sleep(0.0001)

        if shiftKey:
            CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x38, True))
            time.sleep(0.0001)

        CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, keyCode, True))
        time.sleep(0.0001)

        CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, keyCode, False))
        time.sleep(0.0001)

        if shiftKey:
            CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x38, False))
            time.sleep(0.0001)

    def Type(self, text):
        for key in text:
            self.KeyDown(key)
            self.KeyUp(key)
```

Here is the demo code using above class:

```
# DEMO
if __name__ == '__main__':
    keyboard = Keyboard()
    if sys.platform == "darwin":
        keyboard.Type('Hello World!')
    elif sys.platform == "win32":
        print("Error: Platform not supported!")
```

which will simulate typing `Hello World!` text on the current window.

You can run above code as a shell script. Check the link to the [`keyboard.py` file](https://github.com/kenorb/kenorb/blob/master/scripts/python/Quartz/keyboard.py).

Related question: [Generate keyboard events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13564851/55075).