# Arrow keys in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In Xcode does sprite-kit have any type of built in arrow key support? I am currently using the regular swift key codes and there is a delay when the key is held.  This makes it hard for my game controls.

this is how I am currently reading the arrow keys.

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {

    let keycode = event.keyCode

    if(keycode == 125)//up

    {
        player.position.y -= 10
    }

    else if(keycode == 126)//down

    {
        player.position.y += 10
    }

    if(keycode == 124)//right

    {
        player.position.x += 10
    }

    else if(keycode == 123)//left

    {
        player.position.x -= 10

    }
```

I know this is a stupid question but I an new to swift and I can't find any other answers to this question.

Answer (score 5):

You're not supposed to abuse keyboard repeat in order to run code repeatedly when a key is held.  Instead, keep track yourself of which keys are pressed yourself using `keyDown` and `keyUp`.

The easiest way to do this is with instance variables:

```
var leftPressed = false
var rightPressed = false
var upPressed = false
var downPressed = false
```

You can also use an `enum`, an array of key codes, or whatever works best for your app.

In `keyDown` and `keyUp`, set or clear the key pressed flags.  You can make these functions much more concise using a `switch`/`case`, and if you `import Carbon.HIToolbox`, you'll have some constants available for the virtual key codes:

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    switch Int(event.keyCode) {
    case kVK_LeftArrow:
        leftPressed = true
    case kVK_RightArrow:
        rightPressed = true
    case kVK_UpArrow:
        upPressed = true
    case kVK_DownArrow:
        downPressed = true
    default:
        break
    }
}

override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {
    switch Int(event.keyCode) {
    case kVK_LeftArrow:
        leftPressed = false
    case kVK_RightArrow:
        rightPressed = false
    case kVK_UpArrow:
        upPressed = false
    case kVK_DownArrow:
        downPressed = false
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Then, update the player's position in your `update` method:

```
var lastUpdate: TimeInterval!
func update(currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    defer { lastUpdate = currentTime }
    guard lastUpdate != nil else {
        return
    }

    let dt = currentTime - lastUpdate
    guard dt < 1 else {
        return //so nothing "jumps" when the the game is unpaused
    }


    if leftPressed {
        player.position.x -= 10 * dt
    }
    if rightPressed {
        player.position.x += 10 * dt
    }
    if upPressed {
        player.position.y -= 10 * dt
    }
    if downPressed {
        player.position.y += 10 * dt
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that all makes sense, but what is the kVK_Arrow?  Is that something from the Carbon.HIToolbox import?

Comment: @Elijah Yep; Carbon contains virtual key code constants for every key.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202629/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-mac-virtual-key-codes

Comment: Thats what I thought, but it was still giving me an error after I imported it.

Comment: @Elijah Error?  What's the error?  I just realized I messed up capitalization of `kVK_DownArrow` (I had `kVK_DownARrow`); does it work now?

Comment: Expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type 'UInt16'

Comment: @Elijah My bad; you've got to do `switch Int(event.keyCode)`.