# Diagonal moves with the keyboard in macOS

Tags: sprite-kit, nsevent

My son noted that he could not use the cursor keys to move in [a simple game I wrote](https://github.com/maurymarkowitz/Robocalypse). I followed the [guide found here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705980/arrow-keys-in-spritekit), and now you can move the four cardinal directions. But the game allows eight directions...

keyDown captures whichever was hit first and only returns a single keycode at a time. Now I keep capturing keyDowns and set local ivars and then trigger on keyUp.

It works, but am I missing a canonical method for this? This is my first time on the macOS side, I've always worked on iOS before, so key handling is new and I want to be sure I'm not missing some simpler solution.

Comment: pls clarify the question. are you essentially asking how to use four keys (arrow keys) to capture eight inputs? why not just use QWE/ASD/ZXC instead of the arrow keys?

Comment: @Fault - simply because the cursor keys make more sense in this context, and more generally, I just want to know if there is a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this. Basically, you keep capturing keydown codes until you get a keyup. In the keyup you reset the keydown codes and then decode the results. Works like a champ. `Game.Move` is an enum I had created previously, but for macOS-only code it could be replaced with the keycode int instead.

```
var keys: Set<Int> = []
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    keys.insert(Int(event.keyCode))
}
override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {
    // add the codes to make one of eight cases
    var keycode: Int = 0
    for key in keys {
        keycode += key
    }
    
    // now figure out the result, and default to none
    var move: Game.Move
    switch keycode {
    case kVK_LeftArrow: move = Game.Move.left
    case kVK_RightArrow: move = Game.Move.right
    case kVK_UpArrow: move = Game.Move.up
    case kVK_DownArrow: move = Game.Move.down
        
    case kVK_LeftArrow + kVK_UpArrow: move = Game.Move.upleft
    case kVK_LeftArrow + kVK_DownArrow: move = Game.Move.downleft
    case kVK_RightArrow + kVK_UpArrow: move = Game.Move.upright
    case kVK_RightArrow + kVK_DownArrow: move = Game.Move.downright
        
    default: move = Game.Move.dontmove
    }
    
    // reset the keyset
    keys = []
    
    // and do the move
    doMove(move)
}
```

Comment: there's a bug here. since you're summing the integer keyCodes, you have a conflict in two case: the upleft (126 + 123 = 249) and the downright (124 + 125 = 249). which ever comes first in the switch will override the other. you'll have to make your logic slightly more complex. ex: don't sum the set, but rather test against discrete elements in the set. and test for the exotic (diagonal) cases first, then the orthogonal cases.

Comment: Yeah, changed after the post. I thought they were orthogonal cases until a robot caught me...