# How to get macOS keyboard shortcuts set in System Preferences programmatically?

Tags: c++, macos, keyboard, fltk

On macOS the key combination `CMD+Backtick` is used to cycle through the open windows of an application when using an english keyboard. On German keyboards for example the combination is `CMD+<`. This shortcut can even be configured using `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts` -> `Keyboard` -> `Move focus to next window`.

For my multi-window GUI application using FLTK I want to utilize this shortcut, but have no idea how to fetch the combination the user has set on his or her system. So what I'm looking for is a macOS system call that gives me the key combination that is used to `Move focus to next window` on this very Mac.

Of course if there would be a somewhat builtin way using FLTK I'd prefer that over having to use native system calls.

Googling for this issue is a nightmare ...

**Update 08/10/2017**
Öö's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45602171/2771733) gave me some ideas for additional research. I've since learned that the preferences are stored in `com.apple.symbolichotkeys`, more precisely in key 27.

```
        27 =         {
        enabled = 1;
        value =             {
            parameters =                 (
                98,
                11,
                524288
            );
            type = standard;
        };
    };
```

**Parameter 1 (98):** That's the ASCII code for "b". The first parameter has the ascii code of the shortcut used or 65535 if it's a non-ascii character.

**Parameter 2 (11):** That's the keyboard code for the kVK_ANSI_B ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202629/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-mac-virtual-key-codes%20[Source])). These codes are keyboard dependent. On a US keyboard, kVK_ANSI_Z is 0x06, while on a german keyboard it's 0x10.

**Parameter 3 (524288):** That's for the modifier key:

```
0x000000 => "No modifier",
0x020000 => "Shift",
0x040000 => "Control",
0x080000 => "Option",
0x100000 => "Command",
```

(0x80000 equals 524288.)

So my task just seems to be to parse the output of `defaults read com.apple.symbolichotkeys`, get the key combinations from the parameter dictionary, interpret those combinations correctly depending on the keyboard layout and use these information to set the callbacks in my FLTK app.

Comment: Probably possible using AppleScript. A quick google search yields [this](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/system-prefs.html). You can call AppleScript code using [osascript](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html) in bash (with a system call in c++).

Answer (score 2):

I can't test right now the answer ... but I would first try to `popen` the `defaults` command like:

```
HFILE file;
if (!(file = popen("defaults read NSGlobalDomain NSUserKeyEquivalents", "r")))
{
    return nullptr;    
}
const int MAX_BUF_SIZE = 512;
char temp[MAX_BUF_SIZE+1] = "";
while (fgets(temp, MAX_BUF_SIZE, file) > 0)
{
    printf("%s",temp);
    memset(temp, 0, MAX_BUF_SIZE+1);
}
pclose(file);
```

Here I just `printf` its output but you will likely want to parse it.

Comment: I just get `The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, NSUserKeyEquivalents) does not exist`. But your answer gave me additional ideas for search terms. I'll update my question with some infos I got.