# Simulate key press

Tags: xcode, macos, command-line

I'm creating a program for mac and I need to simulate key presses but I don't know how to simulate a key press. I have done it on windows using winapi, but not on xcode.
How would I go about doing that? (Using xcode on mac 10.7 creating a command line application)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send a keyboard shortcut to a Mac OS X Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705748/send-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-a-mac-os-x-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate a key event by `keyEventWithType:location:modifierFlags:timestamp:windowNumber:context:characters:charactersIgnoringModifiers:isARepeat:keyCode:` and send it to `NSApplication` by `sendEvent:`.

Comment: Where exactly get you stucked? `keyEventWithType...` is a class method of `NSEvent`; have a look to `NSEvent`'s class reference. And if you are uncomfortable with the XCode IDE, feel free to use something else.