# UCKeyTranslate returns junk for non-ascii keys on keyboard

Tags: macos, cocoa, keyboard

I'm trying to map a keyboard scancode to a displayable string on OSX.

I found the technique here ([Convert key code into key equivalent string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547007/convert-key-code-into-key-equivalent-string?lq=1)) which works for all the normal ascii letters and numbers, but for all the other keys i.e. directional arrows, return etc I just get non printable characters back.  What strikes me as odd is that the UCKeyTranslate function used takes an array of UniChars, but only ever returns a single character.

What I'm looking for is something akin to the DirectInput DIPROP_KEYNAME functionality found on windows.

I'm struggling to accept that in todays modern operating systems I'm going to have to resort to hardcoding string values for each of the "unsupported" keys.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: have you looked at the answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263618/convert-virtual-key-code-to-unicode-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to guarantee that you don't have to hardcode those values in your code, but this project:

https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut

Does just that:

```
// These glyphs are missed in Carbon.h
enum {
    kMASShortcutGlyphEject = 0x23CF,
    kMASShortcutGlyphClear = 0x2715,
    kMASShortcutGlyphDeleteLeft = 0x232B,
    kMASShortcutGlyphDeleteRight = 0x2326,
    kMASShortcutGlyphLeftArrow = 0x2190,
    kMASShortcutGlyphRightArrow = 0x2192,
    kMASShortcutGlyphUpArrow = 0x2191,
    kMASShortcutGlyphDownArrow = 0x2193,
    kMASShortcutGlyphEscape = 0x238B,
    kMASShortcutGlyphHelp = 0x003F,
    kMASShortcutGlyphPageDown = 0x21DF,
    kMASShortcutGlyphPageUp = 0x21DE,
    kMASShortcutGlyphTabRight = 0x21E5,
    kMASShortcutGlyphReturn = 0x2305,
    kMASShortcutGlyphReturnR2L = 0x21A9,    
    kMASShortcutGlyphPadClear = 0x2327,
    kMASShortcutGlyphNorthwestArrow = 0x2196,
    kMASShortcutGlyphSoutheastArrow = 0x2198,
} MASShortcutGlyph;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question, but being as you're the only person that answered I will give you the bounty.