# How to capture Unicode from key events without an NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, unicode, nsevent

I'd like to capture key events from any window in the application and interpret them as Unicode. For example, if the user types *Option-e-e* (on a default-configured US English keyboard), I would like to recognize that as "é".

I tried capturing keypress events and calling `-[NSEvent characters]`. However, as it says in the documentation, "This method returns an empty string for dead keys, such as Option-e." If I type *Option-e-e*, then it gives me nothing for the *Option-e* and plain "e" for the second *e*.

Is there a way to combine a series of keycodes (from `-[NSEvent keyCode]`) into a Unicode character?

Or a way to receive an event for each Unicode character typed (like [Java's key-typed event](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html))?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a way to take a series of key press events and get the Unicode character(s) they'd type.

Basically, call [UCKeyTranslate()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/Unicode_Utilities_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UCKeyTranslate) for each key press event received. Use its `deadKeyState` argument to capture a dead key and pass it along to the subsequent call.

Example:

- Receive key press event for *Option-e*.
- Call `UCKeyTranslate()` with the virtual key code (for *e*), the modifier key state (for *Option*), and a variable to store the dead key state.

  - `UCKeyTranslate()` outputs an empty string and updates the dead key state.
- Receive key press event for *e*.
- Call `UCKeyTranlate()` with the virtual key code (for *e*) and the variable that holds the dead key state.

  - `UCKeyTranslate()` outputs "é".

Sample code (the function to call for each key press event):

```
/**
 * Returns the Unicode characters that would be typed by a key press.
 *
 * @param event A key press event.
 * @param deadKeyState To capture multi-keystroke characters (e.g. Option-E-E for "é"), pass a reference to the same
 *      variable on consecutive calls to this function. Before the first call, you should initialize the variable to 0.
 * @return One or more Unicode characters.
 */
CFStringRef getCharactersForKeyPress(NSEvent *event, UInt32 *deadKeyState)
{
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547007/convert-key-code-into-key-equivalent-string
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263618/convert-virtual-key-code-to-unicode-string

    TISInputSourceRef currentKeyboard = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource();
    CFDataRef layoutData = TISGetInputSourceProperty(currentKeyboard, kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData);
    const UCKeyboardLayout *keyboardLayout = (const UCKeyboardLayout *)CFDataGetBytePtr(layoutData);

    CGEventFlags flags = [event modifierFlags];
    UInt32 modifierKeyState = (flags >> 16) & 0xFF;

    const size_t unicodeStringLength = 4;
    UniChar unicodeString[unicodeStringLength];
    UniCharCount realLength;

    UCKeyTranslate(keyboardLayout,
                   [event keyCode],
                   kUCKeyActionDown,
                   modifierKeyState,
                   LMGetKbdType(),
                   0,
                   deadKeyState,
                   unicodeStringLength,
                   &realLength,
                   unicodeString);
    CFRelease(currentKeyboard);
    return CFStringCreateWithCharacters(kCFAllocatorDefault, unicodeString, realLength);
}
```

Comment: @ErikAigner I don't remember. Have you tested to confirm that 8 is indeed the correct amount? Feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

subclass the view/window you want to capture the "é" event in and add this instance variable

```
BOOL optionE_Pressed;
```

then, override keyDown: with this

```
-(void) keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSString *chars = theEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers;
    unichar aChar = [chars characterAtIndex: 0];

    if (aChar==101 && [theEvent modifierFlags]&NSAlternateKeyMask) {
        optionE_Pressed=YES;
    }
    else if (aChar==101 && optionE_Pressed) {
        NSLog(@"spanish é pressed");
    }
    else {
        optionE_Pressed=NO;
    }

    [super keyDown:theEvent];
}
```

The Boolean variable "optionE_Pressed" is activated when the user holds down the option and e keys. If the next key that is pressed is e, meaning that they have effectively created a spanish é, then it will log "spanish é pressed." Otherwise, the Boolien is switched back to NO. The "super" call at the end allows the user to still be able to type all events as normal

Comment: Interesting that you use `-[NSEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers]` — I hadn't thought of using that to capture dead keys. However, I'm looking for a more general solution than your answer. It needs to work for any key combination and keyboard layout, not just Option-e-e on the default US keyboard layout. If you can think of a way to adapt your answer accordingly, please do.