# Send a keystroke to OS X programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, macos-carbon

How would you simulate the keystroke `ö` on Mac OS X programmatically?

This isn't just a randomly chosen character, I know you can simulate all ASCII characters as well as some special ones like `Esc`, `Backspace`, etc using either an embedded Applescript or `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent`. But what about all those keys for which a CGKeyCode isn't defined? There must be a way!

Comment: The accepted answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/1918841/3009) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: @highlycaffeinated I read the source code you mentioned but it only works for ASCII, I need keycodes for chars like `õ`, `ñ`, `é`, `č`, etc.

Comment: There's no single keycode for accented characters. Normal input of them requires multiple keypresses, and so does simulated input. You should also look at [CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH202-DontLinkElementID_10)

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I think `CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString` is the right answer, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "ö"` would work if the German keyboard layout was selected. Some keyboard layouts have separate keys (and key codes) for Latin characters with diacritics.

Comment: id of only gives the decimal code point of a character. How could it be used to emulate keystrokes? – Lauri Ranta - You're right!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use CGEventSetFlags to set the option modifier of a 'u' key stroke followed by an up key event and then followed by an 'o' key stroke.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html

If you need more info ask and I will create some code example

Comment: I see. Is it feasible to do this for an arbitrary UniChar? I mean is there a function, or at least a table which maps unicode characters to keystrokes with optional modifiers?

Comment: Not that I know off, if you go to my https://github.com/nathanday/ndhotkeyevent, it contains a class called NDKeyboardLayout that converts ASCII characters into keyboard key codes, you could look at to get some ideas perhaps.