# Is it possible to localize the keyboard shortcut of an NSMenuItem in a "Localizable Strings" file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, localization, interface-builder, localizable.strings

I have a basic localized Cocoa app. For my MainMenu.xib I have the following localized files:

- **MainMenu.xib**: base localization (English)
- **MainMenu.strings**: German translation

I'd like to use localized keyEquivalents for some menu items. For example, the menu item "Align Left" has the English key equivalent of `⌘{` whereas the German key equivalent would is `⌘Ö`.

I tried this, but this does not work:

```
"aXa-aM-Jaq.title" = "Linksbündig"; // German title, this works
"aXa-aM-Jaq.keyEquivalent" = "Ö";   // German keyboard shortcut, does not work
```

Is there any way to specify a localized keyboard shortcut for a menu item in a .strings file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't localize keyEquivalent. As you said the value may change depending on the active keyboard layout. The one approach is to use virtual keycode (position of the key on keyboard). Use this virtual keycode to translate it to string.

Recipe here: [Convert key code into key equivalent string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547007/convert-key-code-into-key-equivalent-string)

From `MASShortcut.framework` documentation:

> For example for the `^2` keyboard shortcut
>   (`kVK_ANSI_2+NSControlKeyMask`  to be precise) the `keyCodeString` is
>   `2` on the US keyboard, but `ě` when  the Czech keyboard layout is
>   active. See the spec for details.

From `Events.h`

```
/*
 *  Summary:
 *    Virtual keycodes
 *  
 *  Discussion:
 *    These constants are the virtual keycodes defined originally in
 *    Inside Mac Volume V, pg. V-191. They identify physical keys on a
 *    keyboard. Those constants with "ANSI" in the name are labeled
 *    according to the key position on an ANSI-standard US keyboard.
 *    For example, kVK_ANSI_A indicates the virtual keycode for the key
 *    with the letter 'A' in the US keyboard layout. Other keyboard
 *    layouts may have the 'A' key label on a different physical key;
 *    in this case, pressing 'A' will generate a different virtual
 *    keycode.
 */
enum {
  kVK_ANSI_A                    = 0x00,
  kVK_ANSI_S                    = 0x01,
  kVK_ANSI_D                    = 0x02,
  kVK_ANSI_F                    = 0x03,
  kVK_ANSI_H                    = 0x04,
  kVK_ANSI_G                    = 0x05,
  kVK_ANSI_Z                    = 0x06,
  kVK_ANSI_X                    = 0x07,
  kVK_ANSI_C                    = 0x08,
  kVK_ANSI_V                    = 0x09,
  kVK_ANSI_B                    = 0x0B,
  kVK_ANSI_Q                    = 0x0C,
  kVK_ANSI_W                    = 0x0D,
  kVK_ANSI_E                    = 0x0E,
  kVK_ANSI_R                    = 0x0F,
  kVK_ANSI_Y                    = 0x10,
  kVK_ANSI_T                    = 0x11,
  kVK_ANSI_1                    = 0x12,
  kVK_ANSI_2                    = 0x13,
  kVK_ANSI_3                    = 0x14,
  kVK_ANSI_4                    = 0x15,
  kVK_ANSI_6                    = 0x16,
  kVK_ANSI_5                    = 0x17,
  kVK_ANSI_Equal                = 0x18,
  kVK_ANSI_9                    = 0x19,
  kVK_ANSI_7                    = 0x1A,
  kVK_ANSI_Minus                = 0x1B,
  kVK_ANSI_8                    = 0x1C,
  kVK_ANSI_0                    = 0x1D,
  kVK_ANSI_RightBracket         = 0x1E,
  kVK_ANSI_O                    = 0x1F,
  kVK_ANSI_U                    = 0x20,
  kVK_ANSI_LeftBracket          = 0x21,
  kVK_ANSI_I                    = 0x22,
  kVK_ANSI_P                    = 0x23,
  kVK_ANSI_L                    = 0x25,
  kVK_ANSI_J                    = 0x26,
  kVK_ANSI_Quote                = 0x27,
  kVK_ANSI_K                    = 0x28,
  kVK_ANSI_Semicolon            = 0x29,
  kVK_ANSI_Backslash            = 0x2A,
  kVK_ANSI_Comma                = 0x2B,
  kVK_ANSI_Slash                = 0x2C,
  kVK_ANSI_N                    = 0x2D,
  kVK_ANSI_M                    = 0x2E,
  kVK_ANSI_Period               = 0x2F,
  kVK_ANSI_Grave                = 0x32,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadDecimal        = 0x41,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadMultiply       = 0x43,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadPlus           = 0x45,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadClear          = 0x47,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadDivide         = 0x4B,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadEnter          = 0x4C,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadMinus          = 0x4E,
  kVK_ANSI_KeypadEquals         = 0x51,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad0              = 0x52,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad1              = 0x53,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad2              = 0x54,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad3              = 0x55,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad4              = 0x56,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad5              = 0x57,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad6              = 0x58,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad7              = 0x59,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad8              = 0x5B,
  kVK_ANSI_Keypad9              = 0x5C
};

/* keycodes for keys that are independent of keyboard layout*/
enum {
  kVK_Return                    = 0x24,
  kVK_Tab                       = 0x30,
  kVK_Space                     = 0x31,
  kVK_Delete                    = 0x33,
  kVK_Escape                    = 0x35,
  kVK_Command                   = 0x37,
  kVK_Shift                     = 0x38,
  kVK_CapsLock                  = 0x39,
  kVK_Option                    = 0x3A,
  kVK_Control                   = 0x3B,
  kVK_RightCommand              = 0x36,
  kVK_RightShift                = 0x3C,
  kVK_RightOption               = 0x3D,
  kVK_RightControl              = 0x3E,
  kVK_Function                  = 0x3F,
  kVK_F17                       = 0x40,
  kVK_VolumeUp                  = 0x48,
  kVK_VolumeDown                = 0x49,
  kVK_Mute                      = 0x4A,
  kVK_F18                       = 0x4F,
  kVK_F19                       = 0x50,
  kVK_F20                       = 0x5A,
  kVK_F5                        = 0x60,
  kVK_F6                        = 0x61,
  kVK_F7                        = 0x62,
  kVK_F3                        = 0x63,
  kVK_F8                        = 0x64,
  kVK_F9                        = 0x65,
  kVK_F11                       = 0x67,
  kVK_F13                       = 0x69,
  kVK_F16                       = 0x6A,
  kVK_F14                       = 0x6B,
  kVK_F10                       = 0x6D,
  kVK_F12                       = 0x6F,
  kVK_F15                       = 0x71,
  kVK_Help                      = 0x72,
  kVK_Home                      = 0x73,
  kVK_PageUp                    = 0x74,
  kVK_ForwardDelete             = 0x75,
  kVK_F4                        = 0x76,
  kVK_End                       = 0x77,
  kVK_F2                        = 0x78,
  kVK_PageDown                  = 0x79,
  kVK_F1                        = 0x7A,
  kVK_LeftArrow                 = 0x7B,
  kVK_RightArrow                = 0x7C,
  kVK_DownArrow                 = 0x7D,
  kVK_UpArrow                   = 0x7E
};
```