# Find out if a given character is represented as physical key on the keyboard (Mac OS X)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keyboard

In a Cocoa app, given this example `NSString`:

```
Héllö
```

is there a way to tell which character is not represented by a physical key or key combination (Shift/Ctrl) on the keyboard?

For example, on a keyboard with US layout, the keys "é" and "ö" are not represented by a key, but on a French keyboard there is a "é" key and on a German keyboard there is a "ö" key.

Basically, I need to reduce the input string to only those characters, which cannot be typed using the current physical keyboard layout.

I think the [Text Input Source Services Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Reference/TextInputSourcesReference/index.html) might be the right way to go, but I got stuck there.

Note: I'm aware that some characters can be produced by pressing Option-e/n/i.

Comment: You can fairly easily type accented characters on a US English keyboard. For "ö", hold "o" until a menu appears, then choose the one with the diaeresis. Or type option-u followed by "o". Dunno if these sorts of things affect your requirements...

Comment: @rickster Yes, I'm aware of that, but I still need to identify those characters in the string (they are used elsewhere in the UI)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a keyboard character into a `CGKeyCode` using the strategy from this question:

[How to convert ASCII character to CGKeyCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918841/how-to-convert-ascii-character-to-cgkeycode)

The `CGKeyCode` you get back will refer to a physical key on the keyboard. Use the constants from `event.h` to see where these fall on a U.S. QWERTY keyboard: `kVK_ANSI_A`, `kVK_ANSI_S`, `kVK_ANSI_D`, etc.

[Where can I find a list of Mac virtual key codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202629/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-mac-virtual-key-codes/16125341#16125341)

I imagine (but have not tested) that a German keyboard will return `kVK_ANSI_Semicolon` when the <kbd>ö</kbd> key is pressed. (Same location as <kbd>;</kbd> on a U.S. QWERTY keyboard). This would prove that the key is a physical key on the German keyboard.

When you try the same using the U.S. QWERTY layout, <kbd>ö</kbd> will likely return `UINT16_MAX`, which is the default/error return value from the `keyCodeForChar()` function from the first link. This would prove that <kbd>ö</kbd> is not a physical key in the U.S. QWERTY keyboard layout.

I'm not exactly sure how this will work when faced with keys that are physically different from the keys on a U.S. QWERTY keyboard. The additional letter key to the left of <kbd>z</kbd> that is common in Europe, for example. I'm hopeful that that key would be given a `kVK_ANSI_` constant as well, in which case this strategy should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way is to godown to uchr.

You can get a input source property with `TISGetInputSourceProperty()` and pass `kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData` as property name. Than you will get a keyboard layout in `uchr` format, which is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Unicode_Utilities_Ref/uu_app_uchr.html).

I've never tried it, but to me it looks like the intended way.