# How to get the "name" of a CGKeyCode?

Tags: macos, swift, cgkeycode

I need to display a `CGKeyCode` in a user-readable way.
Here is an example:

**For characters and letters:**

```
0  -> "a"
18 -> "1"
```

**For specific keys:**

```
49 -> "Space"
83 -> "Numpad 1"
80 -> "F19"
```

Depending on the keyboard layout the names will have to change. The keycode only specifies the key location, independent from its characters. For example the keycode `16` will be "y" on a QWERTY keyboard, but a "z" on a QWERTZ keyboard.

Since this should be a common problem and is used in OS X for assigning keyboard shortcuts, I wonder if there is any build in functionallity, or a library, that I could use to do that?

Writing switch-case statements for each keyboard layout by hand seems to be a huge task …

I found two enumerations in events.h in Carbon.
One for keyCodes with universal names, which are independent from keyboard layouts and one for keyboard layout specific names on a ANSI-standard US keyboard.
The names follow the naming convention of `kVK_F19` or `kVK_ANSI_RightBracket`. However, I could only use those with a US keyboard layout and the names would be nicer in a simpler way like `F19` or `Right Bracket`.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1971027/1187415.

Comment: Looks good, i am not that much into objective-c, but I’ll try to rewrite it in swift and see if it works.