# How do I find the physical position of a CGKeyCode?

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to create an onscreen keyboard that matches the physical keyboard.  I know that I can send keyboard events for a particular `CGKeyCode`; that a key code corresponds to a physical key rather than to an input character, and that that I can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1971027/15371) to find out what key it is; but how do I find out the physical position of that key?  Is it possible to read out which row it's in and what index it is in in that row?