# Mapping Unicode character to key code in Rust using Core Foundation

Tags: macos, rust, keyboard-events, keycode, core-foundation

I have a Unicode representation of a key, e.g. "a", "!", "ä" or "€", and I want to find out what key code (sequence) is used to produce that character. The resulting virtual key code will be given to [`CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456564-cgeventcreatekeyboardevent?language=objc) to simulate keyboard events.

The solution must be keyboard layout independent, e.g. sending "A" must work with any keyboard layout (e.g. Dvorak).

The solution will probably require using  something like `TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource`, but that seems to be deprecated (and I couldn't get it to work either).

I'm using Rust and `core_graphics` crate. Adding more crates isn't an issue. [This Objective-C solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1971027) might be possible to adapt.

Comment: Does iOS not support another API for sending unicode characters? For example on windows you'd send a `WM_CHAR`/`WM_UNICHAR` instead of a `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP` in this scenario. [`CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456028-cgeventkeyboardsetunicodestring?language=objc) looks like a likely candidate.