# Creating keyboard events that interact with different language input methods

Tags: objective-c, macos, keyboard, internationalization, keyboard-events

I have a Mac app which needs to generate keystrokes and am doing this with CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(), CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString() and CGEventPost(). This works fine with English, however if I change the keyboard input method to a non-English language, the keystrokes I am creating show up as English instead of going through the language I have set.

For example, when I put in a "a" keystroke, if I set Japanese I am expecting to see a "あ", but instead I see a "a".

Is it possible to get these APIs to pass through whatever input method is currently enabled? Or do I need a different API for that?

Here is the relevant code. The variable 's' is a string that contains the character in question. In the example above, it is simply "a".

```
NSRange composedRange = [s rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:NSMakeRange(0, s.length)];
unichar *characters = malloc(sizeof(unichar) * composedRange.length);
[s getCharacters:characters range:composedRange];
CGEventRef eventRef = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent( nil, 0, true );
CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(eventRef, composedRange.length, characters);
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, eventRef);
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Updated with some code.

Comment: Have you tried with `s` is `あ`? Or have you tried without `CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried without CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString (By just putting in "a" in the previous API), that had no effect. Replacing s with あ works, but that is not what I am trying to do. I want to simulate keystrokes, so I want "a" to act as if that key was pressed, going through whatever language is configured (could be Chinese, Korean, etc.) To phrase it another way, I want my app to just do exactly what pressing "a" on a keyboard does.

Comment: An event without `CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString` works for me.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "works"? If you do the character "a" do you see characters in other languages come up? If so, which languages have you tested with?

Comment: My test app posts a keydown event with key code `kVK_ANSI_A`. If the input method is Dutch then "a" is inserted, if the input method is Japanse-Kana then "ち" is inserted. Japanese-Romaji: "あ", Greek: "α", Arabic: "ش"، I didn't test them all. The language setting doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm working with a string (i.e. "a"), how do I get a key code from the string? I have logic to do this using kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData, but that isn't available for languages like Japanese.

Comment: See [How to convert ASCII character to CGKeyCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918841/how-to-convert-ascii-character-to-cgkeycode)

Comment: Thanks, got it working! Feel free to put in a formal answer if you want credit. Technically the problem here was that I wasn't using the keycode. It turns out CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString doesn't really matter here (I am still using that).